# How to change the Y-axis values from numbers to strings in Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) and am trying to change the y-axis (see screen shot below). I tried filling the `yLabels` property with an array of strings. But that didn't work. Any help would be appreciated!

[image: my bar chart]

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    'use strict ';
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ["HTML", "CSS", "SCSS", "JavaScript"],
            yLabels: [
                'newb',
                'codecademy',
                'code-school',
                'bootcamp',
                'junior-dev',
                'mid-level',
                'senior-dev',
                'full-stack-dev',
                'famous-speaker',
                'unicorn'
            ],
            datasets: [{
                data: [12, 19, 3, 10],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)'

                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)'

                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            // scales: {
            //     yAxes: [{
            //         ticks: {
            //             beginAtZero: true
            //         }
            //     }]
            // },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Shameless Bar Graph to show proficency in skills'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For version 2.x, `yAxes` labels are actually stored in the `options` of the chart, and not its `data` as you did.

If you take a look at [the docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats), you'll see that you have to edit the `callback` attributes of the ticks in `options.scales.yAxes` .

---

To do what you want, I just added a JS object in your code :

```js
// Replace the value with what you actually want for a specific key
var yLabels = {
    0 : 'newb', 2 : 'codecademy', 4 : 'code-school', 6 : 'bootcamp', 8 : 'junior-dev',
    10 : 'mid-level', 12 : 'senior-dev', 14 : 'full-stack-dev', 16 : 'famous-speaker',
    18 : 'unicorn', 20 : 'harambe'
}
```

And then in the `callback` :

```js
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                callback: function(value, index, values) {
                    // for a value (tick) equals to 8
                    return yLabels[value];
                    // 'junior-dev' will be returned instead and displayed on your chart
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Take a look at [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c6xdwz8k/) for the result.

Comment: Thanks tektiv—that worked! So I noticed your comment—// 'junior-dev' will be returned instead and displayed on your chart—you're correct, when I try to play with or leverage the specifics data in the `yLabels` object, i don't get the full range i.e. newb to harambe. I am looking in the docs to change make it the way I want; e.g. example I could make `HTML, CSS = 10, JS & SCSS = 8` But where in the docs can you learn how to?

Comment: @AntonioOrtiz Glad I helped, but I didn't get what you are looking for, now :/ --- (*From what I understood*) Do you want to have your graph divided in 10 parts, and have those parts called from `newb` to `harambe` ?

Comment: sorry, let me explain. When I try to enter numbers here (data: [10, 10, 8, 8])  to match the keys in the object, I get funky behavior. Essentially I'd like the HTML & CSS set to 10, and the JS & SCSS set to 8. This behavior seems to match your statement in the comment. Does that make sense?

Comment: What do you mean by *funky behaviour* ? When I replace your data by `[10, 10, 8, 8]`, I get [this result](https://jsfiddle.net/c6xdwz8k/1/), which seems fine to me .. Or else I still didn't understand what you are tyring to tell me, and I apologize for this, I had a long day at work ^^'

Comment: Actually my fault. And didn't make the connection it will omit the upper keys because they're not needed. I understand about being a long day, I have a newborn! Thank you and be well Tektiv!

Comment: This works great, But how do you display the text in responsive. By default, When you reduce the viewport height the chart js steps changes.

Answer (score 3):

Update for the 3.9.1 version (see https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats). It's quite similar but you will need to change the syntax to get :

```
options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                ticks: {
                    // Include a dollar sign in the ticks
                    callback: function(value, index, ticks) {
                        return '$' + value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```