# Add custom tick text in ChartJS with multiple y axes

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

I am using chart-js v 3.6 together with ng2-charts in an Angular 12 Project.

The chart is a simple line chart but with multiple y axes. I was trying to implement the same kind of callback function as in this question or as shown in the official documents:

[How to change the Y-axis values from numbers to strings in Chart.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39167081/how-to-change-the-y-axis-values-from-numbers-to-strings-in-chart-js)
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.2.1/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats

the final chartOptions look like this:

```
options: {
  scales: {
    x: {
      offset: true
    },
    y1: {
      ticks: {
        // Include a dollar sign in the ticks
        callback: function(value, index, values) {
          return '$' + value;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

It seems to work if you are not using multiple y axis with just 'y' however with 'y1' as key it does not do anything. The callback function is showing in the final chart object however no changes in template.

If somebody has a hint where I can find a way to implement or a working sample, which does include multiple y axis this would be great.

As I am working on that chart on a different environment, I cannot access or copy the code freely, so I cannot show the current way of implementation.

Comment: Cant reproduce, seems to be working just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/4h80ayw1/

Comment: @LeeLenalee thanks for the fiddle. With that I found the flaw in my code and I could display it correctly. The error was not in the implementation itself, the whole options where saved as a string and parsed again for use in a different component in local storage, together with some other content, which did not cause any problems without the callback, but with inside it caused the issue. I changed the place when generate the data in the same component as the chart and it worked well. Thanks a lot.